# Why FreeRTOS execute "main's" code after osKernelStart declaration? Code Debugging

Tags: c, debugging, stm32, freertos, stm32cubeide

Checking [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30212710/thread-context-of-main-after-kernel-start) answer made me a conclusion that I might do something wrong
about FreeRTOS handling. This is how it looks at SWV Console

[image]

Code it self is nearly freshly generated by CubeMX
without any spectular changes about handling the task's
(it contains infinites loop's) with osDelays equal to one second.

[image]

- Shouldn't it never get into main function again?
- What might be the problem?

freertos.c
[image]

CubeMX[image]

[image]

```
Multiple errors reported.

1) Failed to execute MI command:
-var-create - * vApplicationStackOverflowHook
Error message from debugger back end:
-var-create: unable to create variable object

2) Failed to execute MI command:
-var-create - * vApplicationStackOverflowHook
Error message from debugger back end:
-var-create: unable to create variable object

3) Failed to execute MI command:
-data-evaluate-expression vApplicationStackOverflowHook
Error message from debugger back end:
No symbol "vApplicationStackOverflowHook" in current context.

4) Failed to execute MI command:
-var-create - * vApplicationStackOverflowHook
Error message from debugger back end:
-var-create: unable to create variable object

5) Unable to create variable object
```

Comment: For the start: What does `osKernelStart` return? Also be aware, that `osKernelStart` is a CMSIS defined API call, not FreeRTOS specific. So mechanis within that function might differ from FreeRTOS' default behaviour.

Comment: Are you using FreeRTOS directly or CMSIS-RTOS?. CMSIS says "When the CMSIS-RTOS starts thread execution with the function main this function resumes thread switching. The main thread will continue executing after osKernelStart.". Returns "osOK: the RTOS kernel has been successfully started."

Comment: Maybe something is causing a hardware reset?

Comment: So FreeRTOS itself dosn't come back to the main function after initialize the schedular but the CMSIS os does even with FreeRTOS on the board? :o meaning what you telling me that behavior seen on the pic's are desirable

Comment: @Jose irrelevant. It is freeRTOS with stupid ARM API. After sheduler start the rest of the main is not executed.

Comment: @OskarGarczyński no it does not. As I wrote it is normal freeRTOS with some stupid macros and nonsense functions from ARM. Absolutely useless. Do not listen to people who never used it

Comment: @Tagli you are right. It simply restarts. And unfortunately it is not possible to resolve without access to the Oskars computer.

Comment: That's confusing rn folks because Iam using CMSIS v1 generated from CubeMX as shown on attached picture (edited)

Comment: @OskarGarczyński find `vApplicationStackOverflowHook` function and put a breakpoint there.

Comment: @OskarGarczyński CMSIS os from CUBE is a normal freeRTOS with some useless macros and a few functions on top from ARM. Nothing to be confused - freeRTOS documentation is important. BTW I would scrap all that ARM nonsense and use native freeRTOS API

Comment: suprisnly watching vApplicationStackOverflowHook gave me some news that wasnt expected. Pic has been provided at the end of the question above

Comment: deleting osDelay(1000); does not bring the program to the main debug printf, what does that mean?

Comment: @0___________ I do think that it is important the different between FreeRTOS and CMSIS, they are different things. Regarding the scheduler, main thread is not the same than main function, documentation is clear about that. And yes, it can return to main function if the calling fails.

Comment: @Jose I think that you do not use it. This implementation of CMSIS RTOS is based on freeRTOS **and**  the `osKernelStart` simply calls  `vTaskStartScheduler()` which does not return. If you do not know how does it work in practice, do not discuss the issue !  vTaskStartScheduler() may fail when there is no enough memory. But it is not the issue here as other task are executed (so the sheduler was started).